# how to render component from another component using onclick in react?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, render

I am new to react js using this code I'm getting the component on same page instead of loading to new render page or window this is my code

here I declare the states to manipulate and i want to render my  component by using onClick method but I get the updateproducts component on same page instead of new render page

```
const [changetoupdateproduct , setchangetoupdateproduct] = useState(false)

return(
     <div>
```

<Button color='success' onClick={()=> setchangetoupdateproduct(true)}>Update

{changetoupdateproduct===true ?  : null}

```
     </div>
```

)

Comment: Please explain in detail what you're trying to do. Why do you need new render page ? Do you want another html file to be loaded, or just an UI refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open page in new tab you can use

`window.open("/same-link?product-id=123", "_blank");`

and by query params value product-id you can set component initial state that component is for product update.